# Django - Exception Value: Unexpected end of expression in if tag

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I can't figure out what the error could be.
I have checked the docs to see if there were any syntax changes but I don't find any.

```
Unexpected end of expression in if tag.

Template error:
In template /home/dhruv/django-blog/blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html, error at line 5
   Unexpected end of expression in if tag.
   1 : {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 :     <div class="post">
   5 :          {% if post.published_date %} 
   6 :             <div class="date">
   7 :                 {{ post.published_date }}
   8 :             </div>
   9 :         {% elif %}
   10 :             <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">
   11 :                 Publish!
   12 :             </a>
   13 :         {% endif %}
   14 : 
   15 :         {% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

replace:

```
{% elif %}
```

with

```
{% else %}
```

************ Doc [about if/else](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if).

if/else can be used following ways:

```
{% if condition %}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if condition1 %}
{% elif condition2 %} # in your case, you are missing condition2
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if condition1 %}
{% elif condition2 %} 
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if condition %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```